# Apple app store showing app not available in country / region when all are selected

Tags: android, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have released a new app onto the Apple app store and Google Play store. Now post release I have had some users complaining that they are receiving an error that the app is not available in their country or region.

I have made sure that all countries are selected in both App Store Connect and the Google Play back end. I know that from the Google side I had not previously allowed all all countries but I now how, hopefully this will solve the issue on that side. I do not understand however why when all countries are selected in Apple Connect why people would still be getting this error.

If it is helpful the app was built in the UK and was built using react native.

Any advice or suggestions?

Comment: So is your issue on Google Play or Apple App Store?

Comment: Apple App Store

Comment: What age rating does you app have?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: It was an issue with the link that was being used. Client was using a link that they had found themselves rather than the one that I provided. Rookie mistake not checking that first!

Comment: Could you possibly provide the links that the client was using and the correct link?  I'm having the same issue, but this post is no help since it doesn't provide details on what the issue was (other than that the link was wrong).

Comment: I can't remember the original link that was being used but the one I replaced with is https://apps.apple.com/us/app/the-app-name/id##########